# jquery: loop through similar divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm not that good with jQuery/Javascript, but I'm sure the following is possible, but don't know how I should start doing it.

I'm using the Google Maps API. In WordPress I have severel posts, where I have mentioned the address in the content of it.

Now, I output the addresses with a simple loop, but what I'm trying to do is read those addresses with jQuery, to put them in an array and show them on the map.

Currently it is only showing the first address it has encountered, but I actually need to loop through every div with `<div class="address"></div>`:

Here's what my PHP/HTML looks like:

```
        <?php

            $kantorenArgs = array(

                'post_type' => 'kantoren',
                'posts_per_page' => '4'

            );

            $kantoren = new WP_Query($kantorenArgs);

            if ($kantoren->have_posts()) :

                while ($kantoren->have_posts()) : $kantoren->the_post(); ?>

                <li class="office">

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                        <?php the_title(); ?>

                        <div class="address"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                    </a>

                </li>

                <?php

                endwhile;

            endif;

        ?>
```

And this is the jQuery that I'm using:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        (function($) {

          $.get_addresses = function() {

            var address = $(".address").html();

            return address;

          }
        })(jQuery);

        var map;
        var elevator;
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.9660922, 4.5574837),
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

        var addresses = [$.get_addresses()];

        for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });

            });
        }

    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look no further than the line `var address = $(".address").html()`, which returns the HTML of the *first* element in the jQuery collection selected by `$(".address")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `var addresses = [$.get_addresses()];` by :

```
       $('.address').each(function() {
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+$(this).html()+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });

        });
     });
```

You can also delete your function we don't use anymore `(function($) {...})(jQuery)`

Comment: And delete `(function($) {...})(jQuery)`

Answer (score 1):

instead of create a function go get all address use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('.address').each(function(){
   $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+$(this).html()+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
        });
});
```